# SQL from per day table to date range table transformation

Tags: sql, window-functions

I need to transform the following input table to the output table where output table will have ranges instead of per day data.

Input:

```
Asin day is_instock
--------------------    
 A1   1      0
 A1   2      0
 A1   3      1
 A1   4      1
 A1   5      0
 A2   3      0
 A2   4      0
```

Output:

```
asin start_day end_day is_instock
---------------------------------
 A1      1        2       0
 A1      3        4       1
 A1      5        5       0
 A2      3        4       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is referred to as the "gaps and islands" problem. There's a fair amount of articles and references you can find if you use that search term.

Solution below:

```
/*Data setup*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Stock
CREATE TABLE #Stock ([Asin] Char(2),[day] int,is_instock bit)

INSERT INTO #Stock
VALUES
 ('A1',1,0)
,('A1',2,0)
,('A1',3,1)
,('A1',4,1)
,('A1',5,0)
,('A2',3,0)
,('A2',4,0);

/*Solution*/
WITH cte_Prev AS (
    SELECT *
        /*Compare previous day's stock status with current row's status. Every time it changes, return 1*/
        ,StockStatusChange = CASE WHEN is_instock = LAG(is_instock) OVER (PARTITION BY [Asin] ORDER BY [day]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM #Stock
)
,cte_Groups AS (
    /*Cumulative sum so everytime stock status changes, add 1 from StockStatusChange to begin the next group*/
    SELECT GroupID = SUM(StockStatusChange) OVER (PARTITION BY [Asin] ORDER BY [day])
        ,*
    FROM cte_Prev
)

SELECT [Asin]
    ,start_day = MIN([day])
    ,end_day = MAX([day])
    ,is_instock
FROM cte_Groups
GROUP BY [Asin],GroupID,is_instock
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for an operator described in the temporal data literature, and "best known" as PACK.

This operator was not made part of the SQL standard (SQL:2011) that introduced the temporal features of the literature into the language, so there's extremely little chance you're going to find anything to support you in any SQL product/dialect.

Boils down to : you'll have to write out the algorithm to do the PACKing yourself.